# Why do I need to have setter methods when getter methods do the same work for me?

Tags: java, swing

Both of the below methods return gui reference types.

If I replace JFrame and JButton return types with void and remove return statements, it still works. I couldn't understand the difference between both approaches.

```
public class JavaGui {

    JFrame frame;

    JFrame createGui(){
        GraphicsConfiguration g = null ;
        frame = new JFrame(g);  
        frame.setTitle("gui");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);  

        return frame;
    }

    JButton createButton(){
        JButton button=new JButton();
        button.setBounds(130,100,100, 40); 
        button.setText("aaa");
        button.setSize(100, 40);
        button.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(button);

        return button;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JavaGui javaGui=new JavaGui();
        javaGui.createGui();
        javaGui.createButton();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have frame variable declared outside these methods and inside you set values to it, that's why you don't need a return in this case.

Comment: You do not presently use the return values of those methods, so what difference do you suppose it *could* make?

Comment: And what does this have to do with getters and setters?

Comment: Do you know what setters and/or getters are actually for?

Comment: when we call getter , it returns something and when we call setter method , it sets some value to somewhere ! my question is when to use getter or setter method and why as per my condition here ?

Comment: You should be creating an instance of your JavaGui class, and none of your variables or methods should be declared static (other than main).

Comment: @info catalyst getters should not be creating anything; they merely return a reference to an existing (probably private)  variable. And setters merely set the value of a variable, and possibly handle any side effects that might go along with changing that value.

Comment: I think you should stick with the create... function names and look into the answer from TheChubbyPanda. Why? Because of PURE functions (see wikipedia for that). That will help you in debugging and maintenance.

Comment: it is kind of a convention of the programmer, not needed in that case, actually more  confusing then helping IMHO. I prefer create* methods to return the created component but **not** adding it. On the other hand I would use some init* (e.g. `initGUI`) method to indicate it is not creating, but putting things together - and that would have no value returned. This init* methods usually are the ones calling the create* ones.

Answer (score 2):

`createButton` and `createGui` should create a button and the gui, and nothing else. While your code is creating them **and** adding the button to the frame and assigning the frame to the global variable.

Please see two different re-implementations:

```
public class JavaGui {
    public static JFrame createGui(){
        GraphicsConfiguration g = null ;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(g);  
        frame.setTitle("gui");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);  
        return frame;
    }

    public static JButton getButton(){
        JButton button=new JButton();
        button.setBounds(130,100,100, 40); 
        button.setText("aaa");
        button.setSize(100, 40);
        button.setLayout(null);
        return button;       
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JavaGui.createGui().add(getButton());
    }
}
```

or

```
public class JavaGui {

    static JFrame frame;

    static void createGui(){
        GraphicsConfiguration g = null ;
        frame = new JFrame(g);  
        frame.setTitle("gui");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);
    }

    static void addButton(){
        JButton button=new JButton();
        button.setBounds(130,100,100, 40); 
        button.setText("aaa");
        button.setSize(100, 40);
        button.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(button);       
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JavaGui.createGui();
        JavaGui.addButton();
    }
}
```

You would use the first case (returning the objects JFrame and JButton) because you want to use them *somewhere else*.

You would use the second case when you want your methods to build the UI (working more like a state machine).

Answer (score 1):

The methods do not need to return anything because the `frame` object is stored in their class. If it was in another class or in the main method, you would need return statements.

Your JFrame is accessible to both the methods and so you can just do everything within them but below is a nicer way to do it:

```
public class JavaGui {

    JFrame frame;

    public JavaGui() {
        GraphicsConfiguration g = null;
        frame = new JFrame(g);  
        frame.setTitle("gui");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);  
    }

    public void createButton(){
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(130,100,100, 40); 
        button.setText("aaa");
        button.setSize(100, 40);
        button.setLayout(null);

        frame.add(button);      
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaGui gui = new JavaGui();
        gui.createButton();     
    }
}
```

Comment: i removed static keyword from both methods and made JavaGui object in main method... plz edit answer as per my edited question

Comment: Yep, just did that.

Comment: there is an error of "non-static variable reference from static " .

Comment: That's because you need the static modifiers unless you create an instance of the class. I'll edit my answer to explain to you.

Comment: i saw the changes in your code .   but you didnt explain the condition(s) where to use getter or setter (what things to see before using getter or setter?) ? because here in my code above getter methods fulfill my needs then why we use setter methods for what change and for what reason?

Comment: I think you are confusing getter and setter methods with something else. These are getter and setters: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp